# MVC QueryString into Dynamic Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to populate a Dynamic object with Query String parameters?

This is so that my search parameters in the QS can vary without binding them directly to a container object or having to change the signature of the search method.

e.g.

Inbound URL: www.test.com/Home/Search?name=john&product=car&type=open&type=all

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    dynamic searchParams = // **something magic here**

    var model = getResults(searchParams);
    return View(model);
}
```

The populated searchParams object should look like:

```
{
    name = "john",
    product = "car",
    type = { "open", "all" }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution can be that you build up an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) from the [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which is a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).

It's easy to write the transformation and you can put it inside an extension method:

```
public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions:
{
    public static dynamic ToExpando(this NameValueCollection valueCollection)
    {
        var result = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var key in valueCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            result.Add(key, valueCollection[key]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And in your controller you can use like:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    dynamic searchParams = Request.QueryString.ToExpando();

    DoSomething(searchParams.name);  
    var model = getResults(searchParams);
    return View(model);
}
```

Note: You will need to do some additional transformation to handle to `type` property which won't be automatically an array by default.

Comment: I agree that this would be a nice reusable wrapper to solve the problem.

Comment: Having tried this the `type` property gets parsed as a csv string so it is perfectly usable as is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick

```
dynamic searchParams = new
            {
                name = "john",
                product = "car",
                type = new {aa =  "open", bb = "all"}
            };
```

Swapping out the strings for your query string values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I considered this approach but it still binds me to having to know what values to look for when constructing this object.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use dynamic object and do following:

```
public class QSValues : DynamicObject
    {
        readonly Dictionary<string, object> dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            dynamicProperties[binder.Name] = value;

            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            return dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        }
```

and then parse QueryString parameters

Comment: I would rather use the accepted answer, but thanks for showing how it would be possible through inheritance.